# A seemingly canonical preprint style in mathematics

Tags: formatting

There seems to exist a style for preprints that is common on arxiv.org. A completely (!) random example which I have picked up just now illustrates that style.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.2775.pdf

This style seems to include the following, not necessarily complete list of features:

- Title in bold and all caps
- Authors names in all caps
- a footnote including mathematics classification and keywords
- ...

I suppose that there is a canonical set of latex commands, with a canonical set of possible variations that conform to this style. Can you explain this to me, and provide me with some reference? I do not even know the name of that style.

Comment: You can download the TeX source from arXiv to learn what tricks someone used for a given preprint. Eg http://arxiv.org/format/1305.2775v1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the [`amsart`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsart) class: you can see more details on [CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/pkg/amsart) or [read the docs online](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsart).

Comment: it's not "bare" `amsart` -- that has equation numbers on the left.  so at least the `[reqno]` option has been specified.